# how to use row validate rule after cell changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How can I use my row validate rule every time a cell is changed?
I have int 4 columns: X, Y, Z, W. each cell has is own validate rule and I need to validate that the sum of X + Z is not above the limit, the same for the sum of Y + W.
I want to validate it each time the user changes the value of the cell.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="targetsDataGrid" ItemsSource="{x:Static local:Position.EmptyPositions}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" Height="210" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="All" CanUserResizeRows="False" Margin="0,32,0,0" CellEditEnding="TargetsDataGrid_CellEditEnding">
  <DataGrid.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.35"/>
  </DataGrid.Background>
  <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
    <local:RowValidationRule/>
  </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
  <DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate>
      <Grid Margin="0,-2,0,-2" ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
        <Ellipse StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="!" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="errorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="-2"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
          </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="X" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource errorStyle}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
          <Binding Path="X">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
              <local:PositionValidationRuleX/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
          </Binding>
        </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
      </DataGridTextColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Y" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource errorStyle}">
      <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="Y">
          <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <local:PositionValidationRuleY />
          </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
      </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Z" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource errorStyle}" >
      <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="Z">
          <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <local:PositionValidationRuleZ />
          </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
      </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="W" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource errorStyle}" >
      <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="W">
          <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <local:PositionValidationRuleW />
          </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
      </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

While binding the property assign 'UpdateSourceTrigger' property to 'PropertyChanged'

For row validation, Instead of adding a ValidationRule to the RowValidationRules property of the DataGrid you can implement the INotifyDataErrorInfo interface in the view model class and raise its ErrorChanged event whenever you want to refresh the status of a row/item.

Comment: I added it to the DataGridTextColumn binding.
Now the cell validation is validating while I'm typing, but the row validation is still validating only when I press enter and creating a new row.
I need it to validate while or after the user finish type in the cell.